# Cohort updating in moodle

Tags: mysql, moodle

I'm trying to add users to cohort directly via mysql in moodle 2.6.

I'm almost success my operation , I have 1 strange thing. 
I added user to table mdl_cohort_members and in cohort i can see that i have 2 users. 
When I want to check It in enroll method in course setting i see that I can see that 1 student is missing. When i click for settings of cohort group and after that go back i see updated 2 users. Can You tell me what is going on ? Moodle refreshing database or something ? 
How to do it without any clicking ?

Some News:
I found that in cohort/assign.php catalog there is an option to add users , I can't find direct SQL statement to this , maybe somebody did that or know how to find it

I am almost sure that is that scrap of code:

```
if (optional_param('add', false, PARAM_BOOL) && confirm_sesskey()) {
$userstoassign = $potentialuserselector->get_selected_users();
if (!empty($userstoassign)) {

    foreach ($userstoassign as $adduser) {
        cohort_add_member($cohort->id, $adduser->id);
    }

    $potentialuserselector->invalidate_selected_users();
    $existinguserselector->invalidate_selected_users();
}
}
```

and from cohort/lib.php

```
function cohort_add_member($cohortid, $userid) {
global $DB;
//I see below that is doing the same as my sql , but why it's working via admin panel and not working via mysql only ??
if ($DB->record_exists('cohort_members', array('cohortid'=>$cohortid, 'userid'=>$userid))) {
    // No duplicates!
    return;
}
$record = new stdClass();
$record->cohortid  = $cohortid;
$record->userid    = $userid;
$record->timeadded = time();
$DB->insert_record('cohort_members', $record);

$cohort = $DB->get_record('cohort', array('id' => $cohortid), '*', MUST_EXIST);

$event = \core\event\cohort_member_added::create(array(
    'context' => context::instance_by_id($cohort->contextid),
    'objectid' => $cohortid,
    'relateduserid' => $userid,
));
$event->add_record_snapshot('cohort', $cohort);
$event->trigger();
}
```

Comment: why don't you the moodle cohort_add_member($cohortid, $userid) function in your script with require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/cohort/lib.php');i just try that and it works for me